# How to copy and paste an entire file across different Linux accounts?

Tags: linux, vi

I need to copy a configuration file from one linux account to another account. Since I do not have the permission I couldn't scp. So, how to `yang` and `put` the entire file across the accounts? File has 100s of lines so, it is not possible to copy, paste by mouse. I'm using putty.

Comment: different Linux accounts or different Linux servers?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `PuTTY` then you can use `scp` - both use the SSH protocol and require  a user login.

Since you are comfortable using `PuTTY`, try using [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), which implements the scp linux command with a GUI. Use the same credentials as you do for PuTTY.

Comment: I'm accessing the 2 servers from my windows PC. I have the permissions to access those servers. But those servers are not interconnected. So, I cant use the `scp`. Only way I have is, I have to copy to my windows PC by `WinSCP` then again `WinSCP` from windows PC to other server.

Comment: Are you connecting to the servers with a `password`, or a `private key file`?

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm looking for a solution just copy and paste the contents here and there. If that is not possible just doing WinSCP is easy for me.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's possible here for you. I believe your servers can connect to each other with any config changes - are they both public facing (meaning can you access either of them through WinSCP from anywhere)